# Makefile with static and shared library

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, makefile

I'm starting with creating Makefile. I write simple Makefile, which create two library, static and dynamica and use to compile executable file. The files for the operation of the program are in individual folders: *.c in src, *.h in include,
*.a and *.so in lib and executable file in bin. The rest are in the makefile folder. My Makefile create all files but cant find files. I use VPATH, and -L in gcc. But that's not work. I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Thanks for all help.

```
vpath %.c src

vpath %.h include

vpath %.a lib

vpath %.so lib

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $<

%: %.o
    gcc -o ./bin/$@ $^  -L./lib -I./bin

libj%.a: %j.o
    ar rs ./lib/$@ $^ 

lib%r.so: p%.o
    gcc -shared -o ./lib/$@ $^  -L./lib


prog: prog.o libjp.a libgr.so

prog.o: prog.c libgr.h libjp.h

libjp.a: pj.o pp.o

pj.o: pj.c

pp.o: pp.c

libgr.so: pg.o pr.o

pg.o: pg.c
    
pr.o: pr.c
```

Comment: You always know your recipe is wrong when it's creating some file other than exactly `$@`.  Make will set the variable `$@` to the file that it expects your recipe to create.  If your recipe creates some _other_ file, like `./bin/$@` or `./lib/$@` then it will never work.

Comment: So, how can I change it to make it work but keep the directory tree structure at the same time?

Comment: You have to change the target of your recipes to be the right thing.  Instead of `libj%.a`, if you want the file to be in `./lib` the target has to be `./lib/libj%.a`.  Now make knows where that target should go and will set `$@` correctly.  Then, of course, you have to change the target `libjp.a: ...` to `./lib/libjp.a: ...` and then of course you have to change the prerequisite `prog: ... libjp.a` to `prog: ... ./lib/libjp.a`.  Make can't imagine where all these files should go!  You have to tell it.

Comment: Okay, than you very much. But I have other problem,error while loading shared libraries: lib/libgr.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory/ .How I should set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, when libraries is in other folder than executable file?

Comment: There are many ways to do it, it all depends on what you want.  You've already described one of them: add the directory to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, like this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/lib`.  To be clear, you run this in your _shell_ before you start your program... you don't put it in your makefile.

Comment: Okey, i try this. But, I dont know in which folder I should write this. I try in folder where i have other folder in necessary files. But it still doesn't work.
command return : lib/libgr.so =>not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "in which folder", you have to do it your shell before you run your program.

So, if you run this:

```
$ make

$ ./bin/prog
```

and you get an error, you should use this:

```
$ make

$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/lib

$ ./bin/prog
```

Do *NOT* put the setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` inside the makefile as I mentioned above in my comments.